# Custom customer attribute not showing in admin customer grid table

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer-attribute

I have created an ph:Number customer attribute for the customer registration form . But now i am facing an issue in which that attribute in not showing in the back-end customer grid

[image]

the phone number attribute in the above picture is what i created and the code is mentioned below

Method in my Install Schema

```
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customField = "custom_field";
        $customFieldLabel = "Phone Number";
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $customField);

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $customField, [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => $customFieldLabel,
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 990,
            'position' => 990,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $customField);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);

        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
```

This customer attribute is missing in the below grid

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Below way ..

you need to create `etc/indexer.xml` with the following contents. In this example I'm adding mobile attribute and it's type is text (database column type)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid">
        <fieldset name="customer">
            <field name="custom_field" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="text" />
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

While creating your attribute via `InstallData.php`, `'is_used_in_grid' => 1`, should be set.

After all these code setup, you have to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 2):

Hi Make below attribute as 1

```
   is_used_in_grid: 1
   is_visible_in_grid: 1
   is_filterable_in_grid: 1
   is_searchable_in_grid: 1
```

and then run indexer , after that it will display.

Comment: I have added changes as mentioned above, it's showing in grid but value is blank in magento 2.2.11. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomerSetupFactory to create customer attribute.

```
 use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory; // add to construct also

 $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
 $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
 $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

 $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_field', [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Phone Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 990,
            'position' => 990,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_field');
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);

        //directly save the attribute.
        $attribute->save();
```

Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

/**
 * Class AddCustomerPhoneNumberAttribute
 * @package Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data
 */
class AddCustomerPhoneNumberAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    protected $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    protected $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * AddCustomerPhoneNumberAttribute constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ){
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'phone_number',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'input' => 'text',
                'validate_rules' => '{"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":1}',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 120,
                'position' => 120,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'system' => false,
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'phone_number'
        );

        $attribute->addData(
            [
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],
            ]
        );

        $attribute->save();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```